# Give initial value of array and vectorization in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, vectorization

My question is about what is the fastest way to provide initial values to an array in Fortran 90 or above version, for both serial and OpenMP. I can try

(a) `A = 0.0`; or

(b) do nested loops for `A(i, j...) = 0.0` and adjust the order of loops to fit the vectorization (innermost to the first argument)

I somehow remembered, but cannot find the reference after googled a few times, that complier will try to do vectorization for (a). Here is the test for serial level (sorry the code is messy, not procedure-oriented, and some variable names etc adopted from previous replies)

```
Program vectorization_test

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64

  real :: A(20,20,20,20), sum_time
  integer :: i,j,k,l,n,m, m_iter
  Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
  

  m_iter = 10
  n = 20
  sum_time = 0.0
  do m = 1, m_iter

    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    A= 0.0
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )  
  
    write(*,*) 'time 1', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate   
    sum_time = sum_time +  Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate   
  end do 

  write(*,*) 'average time', sum_time / m_iter



  sum_time = 0.0  
  do m = 1, m_iter
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    do l = 1, n
      do k = 1, n
         do j = 1, n
           do i = 1, n
             A(i,j,k,l) = 0.0
           end do 
         end do   
      end do      
    end do        
 
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )  
  
    write(*,*) 'time 2', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
    sum_time = sum_time +  Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate 
  end do   

  write(*,*) 'average time 2', sum_time / m_iter
  

  sum_time = 0.0  
  do m = 1, m_iter
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    do l = 1, n
      do j = 1, n      
        do k = 1, n
           do i = 1, n
             A(i,j,k,l) = 0.0
           end do 
         end do   
      end do      
    end do        
 
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )  
  
    write(*,*) 'time 3', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
    sum_time = sum_time +  Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate 
  end do   

  write(*,*) 'average time 3', sum_time / m_iter

  

  sum_time = 0.0  
  do m = 1, m_iter
    Call System_clock( start, rate )
    do i = 1, n
      do j = 1, n      
        do k = 1, n
           do l = 1, n
             A(i,j,k,l) = 0.0
           end do 
         end do   
      end do      
    end do        
 
    Call System_clock( finish, rate )  
  
    write(*,*) 'time 4', Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate  
    sum_time = sum_time +  Real( finish - start, wp ) / rate 
  end do   
  write(*,*) 'average time 4', sum_time / m_iter
    
end program vectorization_test
```

I got  `average time   3.76699973E-05,  average time 2   5.98790008E-04,  average time 3   6.55650045E-04, average time 4   3.10386019E-03` from `gfortran-11 -o3` on my laptop with 16 GB memory. On computing center with 384 GB memory, I got  `average time   4.75034976E-05, average time 2  , 4.47604398E-04, average time 3   4.70327737E-04, average time 4   4.14085982E-04`. Larger dimensions similar trend.

Not sure if this holds for other compilers. Seems the innermost loop is most critical for vectorization.

So my questions are
(1) is there any reference for this issue on vectorization and initialization of array;
(2) if I use OpenMP, shall I use a single loop for one variable, `A(i,:,:,:) = 0.0` something like that?

P.S. The initialization of array is mostlikely not the bottleneck, so the question is more belong to my curious.

Comment: This depends on many details, but if it measures anything, it is the memory bandwith that is relevant here. It is very important to consider what specific hardware you are using and how many threads you are using. Any hyperthreading?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just `i7-5600U CPU`  with 16 GB memory on my old laptop. I tried once on `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6148 CPU` on computing center with `ifort` got almost zero results in various dimensions of arrays.

Comment: Laptops will not be optimized for memory bandwith. But do you want to optimize your code for laptops or for larger machines?

Comment: Ultimately for the project is yes, it will be with intel xeon with >100GB memory cluster node. But the initialization of array is mostlikely not the bottle neck, so the question is more belong to my curious.

Comment: In that case test and measure. I doubt there is any universal silver bullet.

Comment: With a 20X20X20X20 real array (i.e. 0.61 MBytes) you will be measuring the speed of (one of) the cache(s). Is this what you want?

Comment: So far it can be up to 60*60*60*60, not sure if I shall need any larger array; i would like to see the timing from different approaches and possible reasons, at least `A=0.0` looks concise

Comment: This looks a lot like premature optimisation. If initialising your array is the computational bottleneck, you probably need a better memory layout. Have your profiled your code and found this to be a problem?

Comment: Yes, I profiled. In almost all times this is not the bottleneck, so my question is more about my curious. I mentioned in the comment. I should have mentioned in the question. Edited.

Comment: `ifort` has an option to initialize arrays to zero automatically. I presume this would be that fastest.

Comment: Please god no. If you rely on that you have broken code. Who knows how long you will have access to a compiler that does that? Who know how long ifort will continue to support that?

Comment: FWIW I use this https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/src/arrayutilities.f90 (subroutine `set`). However, it is 8 years old and at that time `omp workshare` was not very efficient in gfortran. I am not sure about the current situation. The difference was not very big even at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try varying to first index the fastest

```
Call System_clock( start, rate )
do l = 1, n
  do k = 1, n      
    do j = 1, n
       do i = 1, n
         A(i,j,k,l) = 0.0
       end do 
     end do   
  end do      
end do        
Call System_clock( finish, rate )
```

Since Fortran is column-major, this means the first index puts values as near as they can be and thus utilizing the CPU cache to avoid excess memory access which is 100× slower than cache access.

In the end I don't think it would make much of a difference, as the compiler is pretty good at optimizing code.

In my testing with `ifort` in release build with parallel I get two sets of results based on the floating point setting:

I measured initializations per second:

| Method | `/fp:fast` | `/fp:precise` | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LOOP | 440.9171 | 403.2258 | Four loops |
| ATOM | 443.4590 | 432.5259 | `a=x` |
| SPAN | 443.8526 | 457.8755 | `a(:,:,:,:)=x` |
| PARA | 445.0378 | 438.4042 | `$omp parallel` |

---

Code listing:

```
program Console1

implicit none

! Variables
integer, parameter :: n = 60, repeat=1000
integer :: iter
real :: x, a(n,n,n,n)
integer(8) :: tic, toc, rate

! Body of Console1
x = 4*atan(1.0)
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(tic,rate)
do iter=1, repeat
call r_fill_loop(a,x)
end do
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(toc,rate)
print *, "LOOP", (rate*repeat)/real(toc-tic), "ips"
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(tic,rate)
do iter=1, repeat
call r_fill_atom(a,x)
end do
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(toc,rate)
print *, "ATOM", (rate*repeat)/real(toc-tic), "ips"
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(tic,rate)
do iter=1, repeat
call r_fill_span(a,x)
end do
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(toc,rate)
print *, "SPAN", (rate*repeat)/real(toc-tic), "ips"
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(tic,rate)
do iter=1, repeat
call r_fill_parallel(a,x)
end do
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(toc,rate)
print *, "PARA", (rate*repeat)/real(toc-tic), "ips"

contains

pure subroutine r_fill_loop(a,x)
real, intent(out) :: a(:,:,:,:)
real, intent(in) :: x
integer :: n, m, g, h
integer :: i,j,k,l

    n = size(a,1)
    m = size(a,2)
    g = size(a,3)
    h = size(a,4)
    
    do l=1, h
        do k=1, g
            do j=1, m
                do i=1,n
                    a(i,j,k,l) = x
                end do
            end do
        end do
    end do    

end subroutine

pure subroutine r_fill_atom(a,x)
real, intent(out) :: a(:,:,:,:)
real, intent(in) :: x
    a = x
end subroutine

pure subroutine r_fill_parallel(a,x)
real, intent(out) :: a(:,:,:,:)
real, intent(in) :: x
integer :: n, m, g, h
integer :: i,j,k,l

    n = size(a,1)
    m = size(a,2)
    g = size(a,3)
    h = size(a,4)
    
    !$OMP PARALLEL
    !$OMP DO 
    do l=1, h
        do k=1, g
            do j=1, m
                do i=1,n
                    a(i,j,k,l) = x
                end do
            end do
        end do
    end do  
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL
end subroutine

pure subroutine r_fill_span(a,x)
real, intent(out) :: a(:,:,:,:)
real, intent(in) :: x

    a(:,:,:,:) = x

end subroutine


end program Console1
```

---

Side note on precision and roundoff errors. I did a `sum(a)` in the end and compared it to `n*n*n*n*x = 40715040.79` which is the expected value.

With `/fp:fast=2` I get `sum(a) = 40738716.0`

With `/fp:precise`  I get `sum(a) = 46579532.0`

The above is very surprising that the precise floating-point model gives far worse accuracy compared to the fast model.

here are the compiler options I used:

```
 [IFORT]
 /nologo /O3 /Qparallel /heap-arrays200 /fp:fast=2 /module:x64\Release\ /object:
 x64\Release\ /Fdx64\Release\vc150.pdb /libs:dll /threads /c /Qlocation,link,C:\
 Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.
 27023\bin\HostX64\x64 /Qm64
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if this is faster than a simple `A=0.0`.

Comment: This is precisely what case 2 does in the question

Comment: @veryreverie - nah, they are all the same pretty much.